# Using ArcPy to open up maps & layouts

Tags: arcpy

I am converting mxds to aprxs and need the map / layout views to be open when the project starts up. Can this be done using arcpy?

Comment: From the duplicate look at `mapx.openView`. If you need more help please reference the duplicate, revise your question and include a code attempt so that it can be considered for re-opening.